# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'? when trying to slice dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My [course](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DAT208x+1T2020a/course/) taught us that the way to choose a specific value in a pandas dataframe is by typing:

```
df.loc([row,column])
```

or

```
df.loc([[row],[column]])
```

but when I tried to do it, I get the following error message:

> "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

What's wrong?

Comment: People without any access previleges cannot handle this question. Please add your code and clearly highlight which part is showing error and paste the full command line error in your code as well.

Comment: Your question is too broad. A lot of thing can be wrong...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you did exactly? What you wrote instead of `row` and `column` or what values they have.

Comment: Assuming your question is about ***pandas dataframes***, but you didn't say that anywhere in the title or tags, and in the body you didn't show either your dataframe or code. (It helps if you show the previous line of code, presumably `df = pd.read_csv(...)`). If this is not what you want then please edit the question to restate it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without a clear example, but I think that where you have:

```
file.loc([row,column]) 
# and 
file.loc([[row],[column]])
```

You probably want:

```
file.loc[row,column]
# and 
file.loc[[row],[column]]
```

I.e. lose the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

No, **the correct syntax for slicing pandas dataframes is**:

```
df.loc[row,column]
```

WRONG:

```
df.loc([row,column])
      ^            ^      # no parentheses () around the [...] expression

df.loc([[row],[column]])
      ^ ^   ^ ^      ^ ^  # no second pair of [] brackets, and no parentheses
```

Assuming that's what you're trying to access here. CSV is only a file format, not a pandas object. `df = pd.read_csv(...)` reads in a CSV file and assigns it to a pandas dataframe called `df`.

- **A dataframe is called a dataframe, not *"variable that contains csv"***. And usually by convention we give them variable names `df, df2, df_b...`